# airflow webserver showing next run as start of data interval

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag like that:

```
@dag(
dag_id = "data-sync",
schedule_interval = '*/30 * * * *',
start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 3, 9, tz="Asia/Hong_Kong"),
catchup=False,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20),
)
```

So it runs every 30 minutes , starting today in my timezone. No catchup....
In the webserver UI I have these different fields :

[image]

What I find strange from these fields is the next run time... I was looking at it between 21:01 and 21:29 ... and it's still show the next run as 21:00 or in another words the next run is past...

Does the next run mean the logical date in airflow ? that is the start time of the interval ? it is quite non intuitive to look at it and see a time in the past...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the logical date.

> it is quite non intuitive to look at it and see a time in the past...

If you consider data pipeline flows it is intuitive.
Lets explain this with daily run for simplicity.
In daily interval the data of date `2023-02-01` is ready in `2023-02-02` meaning that in `2023-02-02 00:00` you have the full data of `2023-02-01 00:00` - `2023-02-02 00:00` thus only in `2023-02-02` you can start running the workflow of `2023-02-01`. Same goes for hourly jobs.
Normally you care about what date is ready and less about the timestamp it actually run.

If you are looking to know when the process is going to run you have that in the Graph View when you hover over the Next Run indicator:

[image]

In this case (using your code  example) the run of logical date `2023-03-09 14:30` will start in `2023-03-09 15:00` as this is when the 30 minute interval of the run ends, this will happen in 7 minutes (Note that the current time is `14:53 UTC` as shown in the yellow bar)